# "false Transaction mined but execution failed" after trying to make a Transfer From using openzeppelin

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix, openzeppelin

After deploying and using the transferFrom function, it is giving the following error: **"false Transaction mined but execution failed"**. This is the code:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TransferToken {
    function transferFrom(IERC20 token, address from, address to, uint amount) public{
        token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

**How can I transfer my ERC20 token from wallet 1 to wallet 2?** Without asking for authorization? Because this will be a form of withdrawal from an NFT game. Wallet 1 will be mine, and wallet 2 will be the player's.

Answer (score 0):

The approval mechanism prevents stealing tokens from users who don't want you to spend their tokens.

So the easiest way is to execute the `approve()` function on the token contract, from the `wallet 1` (sender), passing the `TransferToken` address in the first argument and total amount of tokens that you want to allow for spending.

This will effectively allow the `TransferToken` contract to spend the `wallet 1`'s tokens.

---

If you have control over the token code, you could also implement a separate function (to the token contract) that would allow the transfer without any previous approvals:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyToken {
    mapping (address => uint256) balanceOf;
    address gameContractAddress;
    
    function transferForGame(address _receiver, uint256 _amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == gameContractAddress, 'Only the game can perform this transfer');
        balanceOf[gameContractAddress] -= _amount;
        balanceOf[_receiver] += _amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I gonna test...